# Add subview to active viewController from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating a application with an sqlite database. I update the database with information retrieved from a web service. I call the web service from AppDelegate like this:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{

    // get new information from web service
    // update sqlite database

}
```

The web service can take quite a long time so I want to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to whatever `viewController` that is active. And of course, remove it when then update is done.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 480)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:testView];
}
```

Then whenever you are done do:

```
[testView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

In each of your view controllers (or common super class view controller) listen for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification which is being sent when application becomes active.

This way you can have custom logic for each view controller without coupling app delegate to other parts of your code by using lots of ifs (if you need to distinguish which view controller is active one).

Answer (score -1):

Because your view hierarchy can take any form, tracking the currently visible view controller is something you will have to do yourself. The exception: if everything in your app happens within a UINavigationController, you can always get the current view controller with this.

```
[navigationController topViewController];
```

If all you need to do is present an overlay, however, you can just add that view to the root view controller's view; all child view controllers are just presented as subviews anyway.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Manually throwing views into the mix like this is not very elegant, though. I would consider posting notifications when various network events occur, and letting each view controller update itself appropriately.